# Send user to a new page via JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are submitting data and then showing the result in a a alert box, what we want to do is send the user to a another page(response.php?r=result) instead of showing the alert.

The code we are using is below

```
function (result) {
            
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                              "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                              "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                              "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);                            
                    }, 0);
                },
```

Comment: If you really want it to open a new page, then the response should be a URL to the new page and you'd use something like `window.location=result.URI;` in the javascript to go to the new page. This would mean the server needs to store the results somewhere to generate the new page though.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like that

```
location.href = 'response.php?r=' + JSON.stringify(result);
```

?